# O !important CSS pesa o site?

Tags: css, css3

Gostaria de saber disso... Pôs tenho um projeto aqui que está sendo necessário usar, (necessário de verdade). Alguém teria alguma resposta para isso:

Deixando mais claro, gostaria de saber se o uso do `!important;` no `CSS` diminui a performance do mesmo.

Exemplo:

---

Esse:

```
.test {
  display block;
}
```

Roda mais rapido que esse?

```
.teste {
   display: block !Important;
}
```

Se sim, saberiam me dizer o por quê?

Comment: Podes contextualizar melhor e ilustrar seu problema?

Comment: Editei pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Arrisco a dizer que se sua aplicação necessita do uso do `!important` ela está mal estruturada e, assim, muitos outros pontos irão influenciar mais na performance do que o perguntado.

Comment: Pesa 11 bytes a mais. :P

Comment: Não, @AndersonCarlosWoss, está direito, mas eu não sei porque o CSS aqui não esta obedecendo a cascata. Ele está pegando o que está em cima primeiro, ao invés do que está em baixo.

Comment: O `!important` quebra a cascata e por isso que seu uso é desencorajado. Para fins práticos, é melhor nem saber que ele existe. Por isso digo que se você está necessitando utilizá-lo, o CSS deve estar mal feito. Mas é minha opinião.

Comment: Poderia me dar um feedback (se possivel) se está mal formatado? https://i.imgur.com/cLRH7bo.png e https://i.imgur.com/CIjlyoA.png pôs está ok, mas como pode ver ali, toda hora que tenho que chamar um H1 diferente, ele não respeita a cascata, então tenho que usar o Important. o big-title uso pra formatar os headers. Vou talvez tirar a formatação do big-title h1